# Json merge left or right Typescript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

How can I merge Json objects so that when a Json A and Json B are merged then simple values (string or number or boolean etc) they get overridden when keys match but when complex values(arrays and objects are merged) are there then there are two outcomes. 
1.) If it is simple array of strings then merge the strings and if it is objects then recursive solution applies.
2.) If it is object then recursive solution applies.

Here is the expected output.
I have tried various npm packages but still looking for a perfect solution.

```
const A = {
    Results: [
        {
            PgId: "pg1",
            Entities: [
                {
                    EntityName: "Customer",
                    Subjects: [
                        {
                            first_name: "Mark",
                            last_name: "woodruff",
                            location: "tenino"
                        },
                        {
                            first_name: "helen1",
                            last_name: "mclean1",
                            location: "washington1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    pets: ['Cat', 'Parrot'],
    isComplete: false
}

const B = {
    Results: [
        {
            PgId: "pg1",
            Entities: [
                {
                    EntityName: "Customer",
                    Subjects: [
                        {
                            first_name: "Mark",
                            last_name: "woodruff",
                            location: "tenino"
                        },
                        {
                            first_name: "helen",
                            last_name: "mclean",
                            location: "washington"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    pets: ['Dog'],
    isComplete: true
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
    const mergedBA_B_overrides_A = {
    Results: [
        {
            PgId: "pg1",
            Entities: [
                {
                    EntityName: "Customer",
                    Subjects: [
                        {
                            first_name: "Mark",
                            last_name: "woodruff",
                            location: "tenino"
                        },
                        {
                            first_name: "helen",
                            last_name: "mclean",
                            location: "washington"
                        },
                        {
                            first_name: "helen1",
                            last_name: "mclean1",
                            location: "washington"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    pets: ['Dog','Cat', 'Parrot'],
    isComplete: true
}
```

Comment: Check out search results for "merge deep". You might even need to write your own custom merging function to do things like combining all values from two arrays (eg. if both arrays have the same value, do you keep both?. If two arrays contains objects, do you do a deep comparison of the objects?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to recursively iterate through the object's properties, overwriting source values with target values.

If you do a search engine query for 'github gist javascript mergedeep' there is this solution:

- https://gist.github.com/kylealwyn/75d9045ea2c5e8d4a1b983005cfaf198

You may have to be cautious about merging values in arrays with that solution. If you want to do that, you may have to include something to handle arrays as well as objects, like this apparent solution:

- https://gist.github.com/danieldietrich/0bd56068825a78321d532ce021d38edc

I have used solutions similar to both of these.